# Dictionary not updated after mapping inner function

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, scope

I am trying to use a map that applies an inner function in order to use a local variable, a dictionary, of the outer function. However, I am not able to modify the dictionary from the inner function. This should be the code:

```
def outer_func():
    def inner_func(x):
        d[x] = 1
    d = {}
    map(inner_func, [1, 2, 3])
    print(d)

outer_func()
```

The output of this piece of code is `{}` in python3, while in python2 is `{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}`. I understand that it is a problem of scope, and then I tried using the `nonlocal` keyword in the inner function (with python3), but this didn't work either. How can I update the dict in python3 using a map and a inner function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `map` in Python 3 creates and returns an iterator.  Your inner function is not getting called, because no one consumed the iterator.  If you had added a `print` statement in `inner_func`, you would have seen that.

If you do

```
list(map(inner_func, [1, 2, 3]))
```

you'll see it works just fine